# UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter causing sample to fail

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security

I am using the latest STS with spring 3.2.11 and spring-security 3.2.5. I have stripped code out of gs-spring-security-3.2-master and used it as a base. I have implemented the class

```
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class MyUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter
{
}
```

and in my WebSecurityConfig.configure method, i have added
    http.addFilterBefore(new MyUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

When I "Debug As" the project, it brings up

```
http://localhost:8080
```

in a blank web page. Even when I use

```
http://localhost:8080/login
```

it still displays the blank page. If I remove the @Component from the class Debug As brings up

```
http://localhost:8080/login
```

and correctly displays the login form. I am using Java-based config.

Any suggestions as to how to get the URL to display properly?

Comment: You have an error message in the logs maybe?

Comment: Yes. I missed it authenticationManager must be specified.

Comment: I dropped the @Component and it now displays the login form. However, I've overridden all the methods in UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter and set a breakpoint in each. None of the methods gets called when i submit the login form.

Comment: I had also forgotten @EnableWebSecurity in my WebSecurityConfig. I also moved the addfilter so it looks like http.addfilter(new MyUsernamePaswordAuthenticationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class).csrf().disable()... and I put a breakpoint in the constructor for MyUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter. The breakpoint in the constructor is hit so I know the filter is at least being added. Still no breakpoints in the rest of the methods, though.

Comment: I take that back. It is stopping in requiresAuthentication and successfulAuthentication. I was hoping it would call getUsername or something like that but after adding logging, it appears that I'm still using the DaoAuthenticationProvider.

Comment: Finally! I removed the Service annotation on UserRepositoryUserDetailsService and Controller annotation and RequestMapping annotation on MessageController and Configuration annotation and EnableJpaRepositories annotation on DataConfiguration and in WebSecurityConfig I added Autowired private MyUsernamePasswordAuthenticationProvider ...; and changed the registerAuthentication to auth.authenticationProvider(...) rather than auth.UserDetailsService(...). I also added the MyUsernamePasswordAuthenticationProvider with Component annotation overriding the authenticate and supports methods.